# Website developed for "normal" sized monitors get messed in widescreen

Tags: monitor

I created a website that works quite nice but later went over to a friend's house and the website was disproportioned and almost hideous on his widescreen monitor. Without extensive rewriting of the website, is there perhaps a script that resizes my website for those on widescreen monitors, or other alternatives? Any suggestions besides "redo your website properly" welcome. Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is how my website should look like:
http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/4453/22425853.jpg 
Here's how it appears on widescreen:
http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/7494/racism.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you did the layout. If you did not use absolute or fixed positiong, the simplest way could be to use a wrapper div around your content and give it a maximum width, like this

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- all the content goes here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

**EDIT**: If you do not have access to the HTML you can leave the CSS as shown and use this jQuery line (it should work but I have not tested it)

```
$('body').wrapInner('<div id="wrapper" />')
```

**EDIT**: I see you are not familiar with jQuery. Code that should be run only when the page is ready should be wrapped as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').wrapInner('<div id="wrapper" />');
});
```

Please let me know if that works for you. You can try

```
$('#wrapper').attr('id');
```

in the Firebug console to check that the wrapper div has been created.

Comment: This is very good, unfortunatly I don't have access to the HTML of the page, only CSS and Javascript

Comment: This jQuery seems like it requires the html to have the wrapper class in it. I can't add this into the HTML

Comment: Actually it will create a new div with id `wrapper`. Did you try it?

Comment: I will try it as soon as I get access to a widescreen monitor

Comment: There is no need to wait that long! You can just try it on your computer and check in Firebug (or whatever you use) the the whole site is wrapped in the `wrapper` div.

Comment: @Andrea Sorry I don't know much about jQuery but can I put jQuery inside <script type="text/javascript"> tags?

Comment: I checked page source and the page was not wrapped in the wrapper div.

Comment: The change is made via javascript, so it will NOT change the page source. There are specific tools to see what is in the page after javascript modification, Firebug neing the most popular. As for jquery, you only need to download it from the site and include it like any other javascript file.

Comment: I don't see anything in the firebug HTML tab. To confirm, I changed max-width to a small value (660px) and did not see any visible difference

Comment: As I see you have never used jQuery, I am updating my answer. Don't forget to include jQuery!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

Set a `max-width` in your css on the wrapper of the site.